# What is the best practice of testing JSON data?

Tags: json, testing

I'm developing a server-side RESTful application which serves json data for its client applications. And I have to test so many various json outputs.
Each json has many properties and their validation methods are different like below a sample json.

So such my use-case, do you know good libraries or web services to test json data flexibly?

```
{
  "system": { // data structure validation
    "time": 1234566, // data type validation
    "version": "0.0.1" // string matching validation
  },
  "app": { // data structure validation
    "id": "1234", // string matching validation
    "command": "do something", // string matching validation
    "data": { // data structure validation
      "hoge": "xxx", // data type validation
      "fuga": 123 // data type validation
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by validating? validating the JSON structure or the data inside your JSON object?
To validate the structure you can parse it to another datatype like dictionary and see if you get any error while.
But to validate the data inside the object you need to validate each object in a very specific way for that object.

Comment: My interest is to validate properties inside my JSON. Of course I can make  test codes to check each properties. But my output json's variety is too much. So I've asked if there are useful framework to check json properties, I would like to use it.

Comment: Since types of properties or fields or even the depth of nested objects in a JSON object varies then my best guess is that writing such library is not possible.

Comment: ok. Taking my complex test specification into consideration, I should develop own test framework of JSON. thnak you.

Comment: Hey @jef .. accept my answer if it somehow helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this link [Just Place your JSON code and Test it.](http://jsonlint.com/) Quite easy.

Comment: I think it only validates a structure as JSON, and not checking its properties.

Comment: can you please let me know what does the properties means? I'm not good at this. I have just started working on JSON.